# Git merge previous commit from the same branch

Tags: git, version-control, git-merge

Currently my brach is in state

```
A-B-C
```

what I want is

```
A-B-C-D
```

where 
D = A + C (take both changes)

I tried cherry picking `A` but it states nothing to commit, working tree clean.

Comment: Can you explain more about what you're trying to accomplish overall? Why do you need your branch in this state?

Comment: As the changes of A and C are already in the latest revision, you can't re-apply them as D unless you revert A and C first. But it's possible to rebase the branch against A's parent and make the history `D-B'` or `B'-D` where D includes changes of A and C.

Answer (score 3):

Even for the same branch, you can use `git cherry-pick` to apply a previous version to the `HEAD` version.

And for the reason why git shows "nothing to commit, working tree clean" when you cherry-pick commit `A,` that’s because **changes on commit `A` is same as commit `C`**. And you can double check by the command:

```
git diff <commitA> <commitC>
```

There will show no differences between the two commits.

And you do not need to add a new commit `D` since commit `C` already meet what you want.

---

Or if you want to reset to commit `A` or to the new version based on commit `A`, then you can use `git reset` command instead:

- Use `git reset --hard A` to reet to the version for commit `A` directly;
- Use `git reset --soft A` (or `git reset A` use `--mixed` option by default), `git stash` and `git pop` to resolve coflict manually and keep the version you need based on commit `A`.

Comment: `C` doesn't have everything I want since it overwrites things from `A`

Comment: What's the output of `git diff commitA commitC`?

Comment: Or if you want to reset to commit `A`, you can use the command `git reset --hard <commit A>`. Then there will only has the commit `A` in commit history.

Comment: what I ended up doing was `git reset --soft A`, `git stash`, `git pop` which caused merge conflicts and I was able to merge both left and right changes in.

Comment: @Pdksock Thanks for sharing the solution you finally took. And I updated my answer with this solution included. Since your problem has been solved, you can mark the answer, and it will also benefit others who meet similar questions :)

Answer (score 0):

You already have both `A` and `C` changes right? So if your current state is `A-B-C` and you want it to be `A-B-C-D` where `D = A + C`, it does not makes any sense coz you already have `A` and `C` in your state.

Thus, when you are even cherry-picking, there is no "change".

I hope that answers your question :)